# Covariance of Brownian Bridge?

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

I am confused by this question. We all know that Brownian Bridge can also be expressed as:

$$Y_t=bt+(1−t)\int_a^b \! \frac{1}{1-s} \, \mathrm{d} B_s $$

Where the Brownian motion will end at b at $t = 1$ almost surely. Hence I can write it as:

$$Y_t = bt + I(t)$$

where $I(t)$ is a stochastic integral, and in this case it is a martingale. Since it is a martingale, the co-variance can be calculated as:

\begin{array} {lcl} E[Y_t Y_s] & = & b^2 ts + E(I(t)I(s)] \\ & = & b^2 ts + E\{(I(t)-I(s))* I(s) \} + E [I(s)^2] \\& =&b^2 ts + Var[I(s)] + b^2s^2 \\ & = & b^2 ts + b^2 s^2 + s(1-s)   \end{array}

Hence the variance is just $ b^2 s^2 + s(1-s)$. However I read online, the co-variance of the Brownian Bridge should be $s(1-t)$. I am relaly confused. Please advise. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 10):

I think the given representation of the Brownian Bridge is not correct. It should read

$$Y_t = a \cdot (1-t) + b \cdot t + (1-t) \cdot \underbrace{\int_0^t \frac{1}{1-s} \, dB_s}_{=:I_t} \tag{1}$$

instead. Moreover, the covariance is defined as $\mathbb{E}((Y_t-\mathbb{E}Y_t) \cdot (Y_s-\mathbb{E}Y_s))$, so you forgot to subtract the expectation value of $Y$ (note that $\mathbb{E}Y_t \not= 0$).

Here is a proof using the representation given in $(1)$:

$$\begin{align} \mathbb{E}Y_t &= a \cdot (1-t) + b \cdot t \\
\Rightarrow \text{cov}(Y_s,Y_t) &= \mathbb{E}((Y_t-\mathbb{E}Y_t) \cdot (Y_s-\mathbb{E}Y_s)) = (1-t) \cdot (1-s) \cdot \mathbb{E}(I_t \cdot I_s) \\ &= (1-t) \cdot (1-s) \cdot \underbrace{\mathbb{E}((I_t-I_s) \cdot I_s)}_{\mathbb{E}(I_t-I_s) \cdot \mathbb{E}I_s = 0} + (1-t) \cdot (1-s) \mathbb{E}(I_s^2) \tag{2} \end{align}$$

for $s \leq t$ where we used the independence of $I_t-I_s$ and $I_s$. By Itô's isometry, we obtain

$$\mathbb{E}(I_s^2) = \int_0^s \frac{1}{(1-r)^2} \, dr = \frac{1}{1-s} -1.$$

Thus we conclude from $(2)$:

$$\text{cov}(Y_t,Y_s) = (1-t) \cdot (1-s) \cdot \left( \frac{1}{1-s}-1 \right) = s-t \cdot s = s \cdot (1-t).$$

Comment: I like your solution but may I know why is $\mathbb{E}((I_t - I_s)I_s) = \mathbb{E}(I_t-I_s)\mathbb{E}I_s$? How do we know that they are independent?

Comment: @GalvinNg They are independent because Brownian motion has independent increments. For fixed $s>0$ the process $W_{t} := B_{t+s}-B_s$ defines a Brownian motion which is independent from $(B_r)_{r \leq s}$, i.e. $$\mathcal{F}_{\infty}^W := \sigma(W_t; t \geq 0)\, \, \text{is independent of} \, \, \mathcal{F}_s^B := \sigma(B_r; r \leq s):$$ It follows from the construction of the Itô integral that $I_s$ is $\mathcal{F}_s^B$-measurable. On the other hand, $$I_t-I_s = \int_s^t \frac{1}{1-r} \, dB_r = \int_0^{t-s} \frac{1}{1-s-r} \, dW_r$$ shows that [...]

Comment: $I_t-I_s$ is $\mathcal{F}_{\infty}^W$-measurable. Hence, $I_s$ and $I_t-I_s$ are independent. Alternatively, you can verify, say, for each simple function $f$ that the process $$Z_t := \int_0^t f(s) \ dB_s$$ has independent increments, and then extend this using an approximation argument.